# Running puppet script on remote machine

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I am working on a vagrantfile which uses puppet script to do the provisioning. As a part of provisioning a lot of packages are installed and configured.

Since the work is still in progress, i would like to run the puppet script on a remote machine i have which has a lot better and dedicated net connection.

So, is there a way to specify a remove machine to puppet script, so all the provisioning are done on that machine? Once the scripts are final i can modify them to work with vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

If your workstation has a slow connection, but you have ssh access to another machine that has faster internet, you could edit your puppet manifest remotely.

To test your manifest remotely, try the following

```
puppet parser validate foo.pp
puppet-apply --verbose --debug --noop --modulepath=/opt/puppet/modules foo.pp
```

Note that the `--noop` will only simulate what will happen.

Once you are sure the puppet module works, you can copy it to your local vagrant machine.